# API Using Web Address

Tags: api

I am trying to access an API by only using a Web address.  The documentation says:

[image]

Is there any way this would be achievable through the use of only the Web address?

I don't need to know this, but I am just curious.

I am sorry if this question is very basic; I'm just learning how to use apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the text explain, this API uses an HTTP Header named `Authorization` to receive a Bearer token. It's impossible to access it directly on browser, you will need to use curl for example to access it directly.

There are a few visual tools to allow you debugging some api that you will be able to do this request, like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) and [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest).